# Excel 2013 VBA select cell P for every row that has data in column A

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a function to put the filename in a specific column (P) of a file. I've got this running if I specify the cells to put the filename in (e.g. P1:P5).

However, I want to get this to run in the P column, but for all rows that have data in the A column.

I know I could do it for just the whole P column, but i dont want it to run on empty rows (they're of no use)

Code I have so far:

```
Sub Save_files()    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("1:3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CELL(""filename"")"
    Range("P2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("p1:p5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D4").Select
End Sub
```

I want to replace `Range("p1:p5").Select` with something that selects every P cell that is on a row with data in A of the same row.

Things to note:

- Column A will always have data
- Columns B through to O may or may not have data

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row based on column A.

Comment: After that, perhaps give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
    Range("p1:p5").Select
```

to:

```
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("p1:p" & LastRow).Select
```